# Can't deploy Scala app:

Tags: scala, heroku, sbt

I am trying to deploy the following app to Heroku https://github.com/matth/juicer. When I run `git push heroku master` from my cloned folder, I get the following errors:

```
[warn]   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
remote:        [warn]   ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
remote:        [warn]   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
remote:        [warn]   :: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.8.7: not found
remote:        [warn]   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
remote:        [warn] 
remote:        [warn]   Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
remote:        [warn]           com.eed3si9n:sbt-assembly:0.8.7 (sbtVersion=0.11.3, scalaVersion=2.9.1)
remote:        [warn] 
remote:        [error] {file:/tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/project/plugins/}default-e1a97d/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.8.7: not found
```

I tried to modify my `build.sbt` file, but nothing seems to work. Here is my `build.sbt` which is in `project/plugins`:

```
import Defaults._

resolvers += Classpaths.typesafeResolver

resolvers += Resolver.url("artifactory", url("http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.startscript" % "xsbt-start-script-plugin" % "0.5.2")

addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.8.7")
```

Answer (score 1):

https://repo.scala-sbt.org/ states

> repo.scala-sbt.org This is a redirection service for the sbt community
>   repository. To insulate yourself from future migrations, please use
>   the proxy URL instead of where it redirects (currently
>   https://dl.bintray.com):
>
> Resolver.sbtPluginRepo("releases")
>   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/

I would recommend using that url, instead of artifactoryonline.

```
resolvers += Resolver.sbtPluginRepo("releases")
```

Comment: Ok so I replaced my artifactoryonline resolver with the one you wrote: `resolvers += Resolver.sbtPluginRepo("releases")`, but it still gives me the same error.